# Vuejs Bulma Datepicker get value

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2

I am using the bulma vuejs datepicker, but I somehow can't get the value. It keeps returning `null`. [This is the datepicker](https://github.com/vue-bulma/datepicker) I use.

My `<date-picker>` component:

```html
<template>
  <datepicker placeholder="European Format ('d-m-Y')" :config="{ dateFormat: 'd-m-Y', static: true }"></datepicker>
</template>

<script>
import Datepicker from 'vue-bulma-datepicker'

export default {
  components: {
    Datepicker
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is my vue instance with the axios call:

```js
Vue.component('date-picker', require('./components/Datepicker.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        releaseDate: '',
        file: '',
    },

    methods: {
        createGame (e) {
            self = this;
            this.loading = true;
            const fileInput = document.querySelector('#image-upload');
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', fileInput.files[0]);
            formData.append('image', this.file);
            formData.append('releaseDate', this.releaseDate);
            axios.post('/games', formData)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },

    }
});
```

```html
<date-picker></date-picker>
```

Comment: *It keeps returning null.* What? What line?

Comment: @acdcjunior Server side if I post it

Comment: You mean `formData.append('releaseDate', this.releaseDate);` then? Makes sense it is empty. I suggest you add more code of the relevant parts (the main template, for instance) to the question (or add a gist like you did with the other).

Comment: @acdcjunior this is actually all, the Problem is that I do not know how to add the date the proper way

Comment: Are you not importing the *My component:* anywhere?

Comment: @acdcjunior I do updated question

Comment: Now, the template, you must have a `<date-picker ...` somewhere. Show it

Comment: @acdcjunior sorry added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a prop to **your `<date-picker>` component**. Two steps:

- Add `:value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)"` attributes to the `<datepicker>` in the template;
- Add `props: ['value'],` to the JavaScript.
- Result shown below:

  ```html
    <template>
      <datepicker :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)" placeholder="European Format ('d-m-Y')" :config="{ dateFormat: 'd-m-Y', static: true }"></datepicker>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Datepicker from 'vue-bulma-datepicker'

    export default {
      props: ['value'],
      components: {
        Datepicker
      }
    }
    </script>
  ```

Now, in **the parent**, pass the `releaseDate` as **`v-model`** of `<date-picker>`:

```html
<date-picker v-model="releaseDate"></date-picker>
```

Passing as `v-model` will:

- send `releaseDate`'s value to `<date-picker>`'s internal prop named `value`; and
- the event `@input="$emit('input', $event)"` emitted by `<date-picker>` will update `releaseDate`.

For more details, see [**Components - Form Input Components using Custom Events**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events).

At this point, after you pick a date in the datepicker, when you call `createGame()` of the parent component, the `this.releaseDate` will have the picked date's value.